# My ListView is showing the object and not the contents of each object

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

So I want to print out a list of movies from the database to a `ListView` and I'm using an `ArrayAdapter`, but when I run the app, it gives me this.

[image]

I think the problem is in the `ArrayAdapter` or the `ListView`:

Code:

My model class;

```
public class Movie 
{
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String genre;
   private int year;

   public long getId()
   {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(int id)
   {
       this.id = id;
   }


   public String getName()
   {
       return name;
   } 

   public void setName(String name)
   {
       this.name = name;
   }


   public String getGenre()
   {
       return genre;
   }

   public void setGenre(String genre)
   {
       this.genre = genre;
   }


   public int getYear()
   {
       return year;
   }

   public void setYear(int year)
   {
       this.year = year;
   }
```

}

In my DBHandle I have;

```
   private Movie cursorToMovie (Cursor cursor)
   {

    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
    movie.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    movie.setGenre(cursor.getString(2));
    movie.setYear(cursor.getInt(3));

    return movie;
  }


  public List<Movie> getAllMovies()
  {
      open();
      List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
      Cursor cursor = db.query(Movie.TABLE_NAME, MovieAllColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
      {
          Movie movie = cursorToMovie(cursor);
          movieList.add(movie);
          cursor.moveToNext();
      }

      cursor.close();
      close();
      return movieList;

  }
```

And in my MainActivity I have (it's here, I think, in the `GetAllMovies` method)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{

   MoviesRepository moviesRepository;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     GetAllMovies();
   }


   public void GetAllMovies()
   {
      moviesRepository = new MoviesRepository(this);
      moviesRepository.open();

      List<Movie> movieList = moviesRepository.getAllMovies(); // Gets all Movies from the database


      ArrayAdapter<Movie> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Movie>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, movieList); 


      ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewMovie);
      listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
  }
}
```

Side note, when I debug it, I can see that the `movieList` is being populated by the `moviesRepository.getAllMovies()` return value and I can see all the movies' name, genre and year.

Comment: By default, an `ArrayAdapter` would show the contents of an array, which happen to be objects in your case. You want to extend the `ArrayAdapter` in order to get the strings out of objects and then set them into the views

Comment: you need to customize the adapter . For better understanding read Customization of List view Using BaseAdapter.

Comment: I solved it by making a toString in the movie class

Answer (score 2):

The generic ArrayAdapter and android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 are meant for a list of strings instead of a list of movies.  It looks like it is taking each of your Movie objects and calling .toString() and putting it in the list view.

You have a few options, depending on what you need to do.

1. Recommended: You could create your own custom Adapter instead of an ArrayAdapter.  This is very common for complex ListViews.  Essentially, the Adapter is what will determine which parts of the Movie object will show up in the ListView.  There are plenty of tutorials online for setting up a custom ListView and adapter.  [Check out this one.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/124438/android-listview-tutorial)
2. If all you need to do is show the title of the Movie, just make sure you are giving the ArrayAdapter a list of String objects and not a list of Movie objects.  Create a new List and populate it with each of the movie.getName().

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you use list of String for example so thats not a problem to use default ArrayAdapter.
But if you have an complex object you must create custom ArrayAdapter and override getView method.
look at my example, this will solve your problem.

```
public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

private List<Movie> moviesList;

public MovieAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Movie> moviesList) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Movie movie = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_row_layout, parent, false);
    }
    TextView movieTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    TextView movieSubTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubTitle);
    movieTitle.setText(movie.getTitle);
    movieSubTitle.setText(movie.getSubTitle);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return moviesList.size();
}
```

}

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a new layout for each row of the ListView. For example, make a layout file named movie_item.xml in the layouts folder and then inflate it when the view is being created in the

```
@Override 
public View getView(int postion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

}
```

Basically, you would need a custom layout and adapter. A simple ArrayAdapter(it is only for strings) won't help you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you're solution is definitely one way to do it, but i think it is are bother to make you're own arrayAdapter. The solution  i found was that you have to make you're own toString methoed in the Movie Class.

```
public String toString()
{
    return name + ", " + genre + ", " + year;
}
```

This works :) i'm happy now

Comment: Glad you got it working!  I was pretty sure that it was calling toString() but I was not certain.  I was going to make this suggestion but I didn't want to suggest it unless I was sure.  This solution will work great as long as each list item only has one string of text.  If you ever need to add additional lines of text or images, you will need to use a custom ArrayAdapter.